# "Closed form" solution of $x(e^x+a) = b$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function, closed-form, lambert-w

Is there a way to express the solution of
$$x(e^x+a) = b$$
for $a,b, x \ge 0$ and in terms of  more or less standard functions?

I already know that if $a=0$, then $x = W(b)$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.
I tried to get this in a form which can be solved by the W function, but unfortunately it does not seem to work. Maybe there is another approach, or possibly its just not possible.

Maybe you could help?

Comment: By applying the Lagrange inversion theorem we can get an analytic expression for the solution (more involved than the Maclaurin series of $W(x)$), at least for values of $a$ and $b$ in a suitable range. What is the final purpose of having such a "closed form" expression? Numerically $x e^x=b-ax$ can be efficiently solved by Newton's method.

Comment: Maple does not solve this.  So I have confidence it is not solved using the Lambert W function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Honestly, its for aesthetics only. I can do everything I need (e.g. monotonicity in $a,b$) already from the equation. I just wondered, since the case $a=0$ is expressible in $W$, it might be possible in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a formal point of view, there is a solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)  writing

$$e^{-x}=\frac{x}{b-a x}$$
(have a look at equation $(4)$ in the linked paper).

This being said, it is not very practical and think about numerical methods.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have found this on my own.

Comment: @klirk. You are welcome ! It looks nice .... but no practical use !